# How to determine if google public stun server is alive or usable?

Tags: google, telnet

I have seen a lot of of WebRTC client libraries using public STUN server like below:

```
"stun.l.google.com:19302",
"stun1.l.google.com:19302",
"stun2.l.google.com:19302",                                                                                                                              
"stun3.l.google.com:19302",
"stun4.l.google.com:19302",
```

I am wondering if the servers above are dead? Because I have tried:

```
telnet stun.l.google.com 19302
telnet stun.l.google.com 3478
```

I get the following response:

```
telnet: connect to address 74.125.204.127: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Same thing happens to other google STUN server in list.

I couldn't get any response, does this mean the STUN servers from Google is not usable anymore?

My question is: Is telnet like the above the correct way to determine if a service is alive or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is should be addressed to Google.

Comment: Actually, it is a good question, even though it's specific to Google. And a good answer will provide a way to test a STUN server in general. Moreover that STUN server is used in any WebRTC samples, demos, tutorials etc. I think people are too hasty in downvoting questions without REALLY understanding them and knowing what it's about.

Comment: @AdrianBer this is a good question, I also wanted to know the same

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033938

Comment: See also; https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

Comment: [https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver) includes a STUN client, highly recommend using that for testing, use `--verbosity 2` for detailed logging output

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I receive a reply when sending a STUN packet to port 19302 on stun.l.google.com.

Your telnet command gets no reply because it is not speaking STUN. It will attempt to open a TCP connection, which fails because STUN is running over UDP not TCP.